# css rendering position and break

Tags: javascript, css, positioning

I'm having big trouble with styling a box with search results.
I just cant put it below the input box (search) and list the results in a pretty good way. It's all messed and not positioned below the input box. All results are one above the others. (In the picture the results are in the bottom left)

[image]

My HTML:

```
                    <li>
                    <form role="search" class="app-search hidden-sm hidden-xs m-r-10" class="searchb">
                        <div class="search-box">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." class="form-control" id="search" name="search"> <a href=""><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                        <div class="results"></div></div>
                    </form>
                </li>
```

My CSS:

```
.search-box .results{
position:absolute;
}
.search-box .results a{
    padding: 5px 10px;
    max-height: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 990;
}
```

My PHP code outputs the results like this:

```
                while($row_data = $stmt_result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<a href='index.php?id=prt&c=$row_data[id]'>$row_data[name]</a>";
            }
```

If its important, my results are fetched with JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.search-box input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function(){
   /* Get input value on change */
  var inputVal = $(this).val();
   var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".results");
   if(inputVal.length){
     $.get("search.php", {term: inputVal}).done(function(data){
        // Display the returned data in browser
        resultDropdown.html(data);
      });
  } else{
      resultDropdown.empty();
   }
});
// Set search input value on click of result item
$(document).on("click", ".result p", function(){
   $(this).parents(".search-
box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
   $(this).parent(".results").empty();
});
});
</script>
```

Can someone help me trying to get it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're giving the `a` tag an absolute position, which is causing it to stack on top of each other.  If you're wanting each to stack on its own line, give it a `position:relative;` and a `display:block;`.

```
.search-box .results a{
  padding: 5px 10px;
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 990;
  display:block;
}
```